# My While Loop is not finishing in R, how do I know what the problem is?

Tags: r, combinations

I am trying to run a while loop on a data frame with 70,000++ rows. I have tried my code on part of the data frame and it works perfectly. But I've been waiting for 5 minutes now and nothing is happening. So I believe that it is because of the large dataset. Is there any way I can expedite this process? This is my code

```
library(arrangements)
assignments <- permutations(c(0,1), 22, freq=c(11,11))
results<- data.frame()


i = 1
 #choose row
while(i < nrow(assignments)){
  Y1_sum = 0
  Y0_sum = 0
# choose columns
  j = 1

  while (j <= 22){
    n = assignments[i, j]
    
    if(n == 1){
      Y1 = potential_outcome[j,4]
      Y1_sum <- Y1_sum + Y1
    } else if(n == 0){
      Y0 = potential_outcome[j, 3]
      Y0_sum <- Y0_sum + Y0
    }
    j <- j + 1
  }

  result = abs(Y1_sum/11 - Y0_sum /11)
  results <-  rbind(results, result)
  i <- i + 1
}
```

Potential outcome here is a data frame that looks like this

`potential_outcome`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using `rbind` to grow a data frame inside a loop is what's causing the slowness. It creates a lot of computationally overhead. I believe this will get the result you're after:

```
# Test data
potential_outcomes <- data.frame(Yi.0 = replicate(22, runif(1, 1, 15)),
                                 Yi.1 = replicate(22, runif(1, 1, 15)))

# If n == 1
Y1 <- assignments %*% potential_outcomes[, "Yi.1"]

# If n == 0 (invert zeros and ones)
Y0 <- (1 - assignments) %*% potential_outcomes[, "Yi.0"]

# Results
results <- abs(Y1 - Y0) / 11
```

The matrix mutliplication `%*%` returns the sum of each assignment row * potential_outcomes vector.